# Defining occasions (by season) without basing it on year in R

Tags: r, formatting

Ok so this question title may sound vague, and since I'm not really able to pinpoint what I'm trying to do, it's hard for me to find the answer.. so here goes.

I am working with hunting data and I need to separate years into different seasons. However, my seasons are defined by the location of hunting rather than by date. So basically a goose killed in Nunavut is summer, a goose killed in Canada in the fall is fall, killed in the USA is winter and killed in Canada in spring is spring.

I was able to obtain a column separating my dataset into seasons based on geographical area.

However, when I try to assign a unique number to each occasion (or season), I run into the problem that when the new year switches over, my occasion switches over as well, since I used a calculation based on the year to assign season number, which is obviously the wrong way to go at it. What I actually want is for one winter (say Sept to May) to stay within the same occasion. However my problem is that I can't use the months as a starting point as my seasons are defined by locations rather than months.

Basically what I have looks like this

```
    Ring_ID Month   Day Year    region  country     Season  Occasion 
    113749265   7   12  1989    NU          CAN     Summer      2
    113749264   10  19  1989    QC          CAN     Fall        3
    113749268   10  21  1989    QC          CAN     Fall        3
    113753009   10  4   1990    QC          CAN     Fall        7
    113753467   10  6   1990    QC          CAN     Fall        7
    113749752   10  9   1990    Delaware    USA     Winter      8
    113749755   10  9   1990    Delaware    USA     Winter      8
    113753258   10  9   1990    Delaware    USA     Winter      8
    113749628   12  26  1990    Delaware    USA     Winter      8
    113749734   1   7   1991    Delaware    USA     Winter      12
    113749739   1   8   1991    Delaware    USA     Winter      12
```

So notice the last 4 lines? I need the 1990-1991 winter occasion to stay at 8 and not switch to 12. But I also need the occasion for the 1991-1992 winter to be displayed as 12.

Obviously with 27 years and over 18k lines of data I can't do this by hand.

Thanks a lot for the help, and sorry for the not-so-clear and very messy question.

Comment: It seems to be more a database problem, you need to define the rules in the same way you are expressing it, the season is defined per country and per months, then you can assign a unique identifier. Then it is a matter of looking for the session information (table/data frame/file) to assign the given session to each `Ring_ID_Month`. I don´t know if I understood your problem very well, any way, please provide information about the meaning of `Occasion` and try to provide a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit better !

```
make.occasion<-function(datelist,data){
dat <- list()
names(datelist)[1]<-"start"   
names(datelist)[2]<-"end"
for (i in 1:length(datelist$start)){
Occ<-data[data$date >= datelist$start & data$date <= datelist$end,]
Occ$Occasion<-i
dat<-rbind(dat,Occ)
}
    return(dat)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is to define a new column with the :

```
  df$date <- as.Date(with(df, paste(Year, Month, Day,sep="-")), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then you could probably find a more clever way to do this but this would work :

Let's just make a fonction to save a bit of time :
Lets make a dataframe with all the start and end date you want (1990-09-01(start),1991-05-01(end))

EX:

```
    sub<- data.frame(start=as.Date(c("1990-09-01","1991-09-01","1992-09-01")), end=as.Date(c("1991-06-01","1992-06-01","1993-06-01")))


### This function subset the data between two date
 myfunc <- function(x,y,df){

     df[df$date >= x & df$date <= y,]
 }

### I use a for loop to get the Occasion associate with the iteration
data.list=list()
for (i in length(sub$start)){
dat <- myfunc(sub$start[i],sub$end[i],df)   
dat$Occasion<- i
data.list[[i]] <- dat
   }
```

Here you go ! :)

Vive les lemmings :P